# Look at card under Masterplan?

Tags: keyforge

[Masterplan](https://keyforge-compendium.com/cards/288-masterplan) is a shadows artifact that reads:

> **Play**: Put a card from your hand facedown beneath Masterplan.
>
> **Omni**: Play the card beneath Masterplan. Sacrifice Masterplan.

Am I allowed to look at the card under Masterplan (assuming it is under my control) at any point later in the game?

Comment: I don't know the game and doing a search seems lots of forums have lots of debates about that card!   However if you can't get an answer here then you can ask Fantasy Flight directly about any rules questions you have. 
 https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/contact/rules/

Comment: If you do, please come back and post the answer you receive!

Comment: I've asked FFG and will post if I get an answer. Have done that before and never heard from them though, so not getting my hopes up.

Comment: always worth a try.  Answer below from aslum seems to think it will need to in FAQ.  my view in games with that type of mechanic is you can always looks at things you've put face down unless the rules prohibit it specifically or there are are other face down cards in same area of board you shouldn't see.

Answer (score 1):

I expect they'll need to FAQ it, possibly either making a new **Game Area** or have the card be in a special **Masterplan area**.

Technically, since the card under Masterplan did not change **Game Area**, it is still in your **hand**. This means you can look at it, play it (if you choose the correct house), discard or Archive it.

Comment: Since the Masterplan ability is Omni, I dont think you actually need to choose the correct house to be able to play that card, a la Wild Wormhole

Comment: No I mean, say the card you put under Masterplan is a Dis card. If you chose house Dis you could theoretically play the card under Masterplan (without activating Masterplan) since it technically in your hand. 

Again technically it's still in your hand for hand size concerns. I'm pretty sure that's not RAI but it is RAW.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a source to quote, but in all TCG I judged, there is a common sense applied to what is known and unknown to a given player.

In that case, as the card was choosen from your hand, and was never seen by your opponent, you know what the card is, so you are allowed to look at it again. But your opponent cant.

For the same reason, both player can lool at both discard piles, as all cards put to the discard pile have usually been played before and the fact they were sent to the discard, is public. 
Same thing if you want to know how many cards a player has in hand at a given moment, how many cards are left in either deck.

Same if I ask my opponent something that was public, like if he crafted a key on the previous turn or not, how many cards are currently in his archives.